# how to send get request to torrent tracker server

Tags: c, get, bittorrent

I am tying to implement a bit torrent client. I am getting my information from here: http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrent_Tracker_Protocol.

I want to send a get request to tracker to get the peer list. Should I set up a udp connection and connect to udp://tracker.thepiratebay.org at port 80? Is this what my request message should look like?

```
"udp://tracker.thepiratebay.org??info_hash=12345678901234567890
&peer_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
port=6888
&downloaded=0
&left=0
&event=started "
```

this is my part of my code:

```
    char *requestToSend;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr; 
    struct sockaddr_in fromAddr;    
    int fromSize; 
    int respStringLen;

    int portNum =80;
    char data_recv[ECHOMAX];

    char *hash="12345678901234567890";
    char *id="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST";
    char *temp ="udp://tracker.thepiratebay.org??info_hash=12345678901234567890\n&peer_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST\nport=6888\n&downloaded=0\n&left=0\n&event=started";
    requestToSend = malloc(sizeof(temp)+1);
    sprintf(requestToSend, "%s??info_hash=%s\n&peer_id=%s\nport=%s\n&downloaded=0\n&left=0\n&event=started\0","udp://tracker.thepiratebay.org", hash,id,"6888");
    printf("%s to send \n",  requestToSend);

   /* Create a datagram/UDP socket */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
        printf("fail create socket");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname("udp://tracker.thepiratebay.org");   
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));    /* Zero out structure */
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet addr family */
    memcpy( (char *) &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length );
    servAddr.sin_port   = htons(portNum);     /* Server port */


    //send request to tracker server 
    if (send(sock, requestToSend, strlen(requestToSend), 0) != strlen(requestToSend)){
        printf("fail send");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Recv a response */
    fromSize = sizeof(fromAddr);
    if ((respStringLen = recvfrom(sock, data_recv, ECHOMAX, 0, 
         (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromSize)) != strlen(requestToSend)){
        printf("fail to recv");
        return 0;
    }
```

this is what I am getting from a torrent file

```
    dict {
    announce => str = http://tracker.thepiratebay.org/announce (len = 40)
    announce-list => list [
        list [
            str = http://tracker.thepiratebay.org/announce (len = 40)
        ]
        list [
            str = udp://tracker.thepiratebay.org:80/announce (len = 42)
        ]
        list [
            str = http://tracker.openbittorrent.com/announce (len = 42)
        ]
        list [
            str = udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce (len = 44)
        ]
    ]
    creation date => int = 1174816388
    encoding => str = UTF-8 (len = 5)
    info => dict {
        filehash => str =
¸¥£öüËXþÐS®(äfn6 (len = 20)
        length => int = 2222949
        name => str = Audacity.zip (len = 12)
        name.utf-8 => str = Audacity.zip (len = 12)
        piece length => int = 32768
        pieces => str = (null) (len = 0)
    }
}
d8:announce40:http://tracker.thepiratebay.org/announce13:announce-listll40:http:                         //tracker.thepiratebay.org/announceel42:udp://tracker.thepiratebay.org:80/announ                         ceel42:http://tracker.openbittorrent.com/announceel44:udp://tracker.openbittorre                         nt.com:80/announceee13:creation datei1174816388e8:encoding5:UTF-84:infod8:fileha                         sh20:
¸¥£öüËXþÐS®(äfn66:lengthi2222949e4:name12:Audacity.zip10:name.utf-812:Audacity.z                         yf3-ûBÎNrl lengthi32768e6:pieces1360:þ]úÙÉÅ'NÕæ+gd3fi6è6¶
```

Comment: Try rewording your question. As it stands, your goals aren't very clear. You should especially fix the title.

Comment: did you check gethostbyname did return a valid address? i think you should not add the http:// or udp:// protocoll string part for its function.

Answer (score 1):

did you check gethostbyname did return a valid address?
i think you should not add the http:// or udp:// protocol string part as gethostbyname argument.

```
struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname("tracker.thepiratebay.org");
if(!hp)
{
  herror("gethostbyname(): ");
  exit(1);
}
```

Add this line to make sure gethostbyname did work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The example given at that website is NOT for UDP communication. It is for communication over TCP, more specifically, HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

If the tracker uses **UDP**, you should not send a `GET` request, but rather establish a connection at the designated port, and then do 4 steps:

1. Send a connection request
2. Confirm the connection request by reading the 16 byte response, and hang on to the **connection id**
3. Send an announce with the connection id
4. Parse the announce response, it's size depends on how many peers designated

The UDP connection over all takes less packets to exchange the same amount of info, but it is more involved in terms of implementing for a client :)

This [wiki](https://github.com/naim94a/udpt/wiki/The-BitTorrent-UDP-tracker-protocol) goes into detail about what the UDP messages are supposed to include. They resemble messages you send to peers (that is, they use **big endian** ints encoded into a fixed length of bytes)

or the [specs](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html) can help